# Windows.Storage.KnownFolders only available for WinRT apps or available in WP8.1 Silverlight too?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I am trying to download a video and then save it the video library; however, it keeps throwing an exception.

```
'Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.VideoLibrary' threw an exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
```

Tried looking [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn639127.aspx) but I doesn't really say whether it is available for WP Silverlight 8.1 apps.

Comment: I read that...your comment made me realize that I was looking at the WMAppManifest file instead of Package.appxmanifest...I now see that listed in the capabilities...thanks